# ModelForm django shows no file chosen when editing

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create the edit of posts for a blog.

When i create the form with the instance all the fields display but the image part appears like "No file chosen"

Here is my model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    publication_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    expiring_date = models.DateField()
```

Here is my form

```
class PostForm(forms.models.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instance.publication_date = datetime.date.today()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ['publication_date']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'image': forms.fields.FileInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'expiring_date': forms.fields.DateInput(attrs={
                'input_type': 'date',
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
        }
```

This is my view

```
    def edit(request, post_id):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
        return render(request, 'posts/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

And here is my template

```
  {% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card animated materialU animation-delay-5">
        <div class="card-block card-block-big">
          <form action="{% url 'posts:update' %}" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" name="save changes" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-success">
            {% csrf_token %}
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What is missing?

Edit; Maybe is imposible because of security reasons?: [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: `"no file chosen"` is the default placeholder for file inputs. You need to click it to add a file (image in this case). There's nothing missing, your code is (should be) working

Comment: I mean i already uploaded an image when creating the post, i need that image to show as chosen but it does not show.

Comment: Can you check in the shell if the file is saved or not? i.e. query a post and see if image has any value. That would tell you if the problem is with *saving* the data or *displaying* it

Comment: The show part of the blog shows the image uploaded. The image is already in disk and can be displayed if i use post.image.url but the form does not show it.

Comment: If i do
<img src="{{ form.instance.image.url }}" alt=" " class="img-responsive mb-4">

in the template it displays the image but the file chooser just shows: "no file chosen".

Comment: You have answered your own question in an edit - you can't set a value on a file input.

Comment: Doesn't No file chosen stand for the Choose file button, which is meant for the selection of new image to upload and Currently: shows currently saved and used image with its path?

Answer (score 0):

When you define your POST method in either class-based views or function-based views you retrieve the form using `request.POST`.

if you have files like pictures in your form you have to mention that in your views like this :

```
form = self.form(request.POST,request.FILES) # class based view.
```

Answer (score 0):

In  `image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)`, specify location to upload your image like

`image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True,upload_to="relativepathtoimages/"`)